# Данные, ввоимые в формы, могут обрабатываться только программами на PHP?

Tags: php, html, формы

Данные, ввоимые в формы, могут обрабатываться только программами на PHP? Или можно написать программу на других языках? 
Я с начала апреля грызу гранит "плюсов", решила передохнуть и вспомнить что-то там по вёрстке, и особенно интересно поработать с формами. В общем, PHP для достижения моей цели - это не перешагиваемая ступенька?

Comment: Серверные языки, так сказать, можно тот же Python с веб-фреймворком Django, Ruby, Java и т.д.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо :).

Comment: js не забывайте

Comment: Вполне можете себе использовать обработку на плюсах, есть достаточно серверных фреймворков на них. Правда они могут быть не настолько гибкими как PHP или Питон ... данные с формы - это либо текстовые пары, либо файлы, так что если сможете обрабатывать базовые запросы и выдавать ответы, то почему бы и нет.